# Keras + Elephas - model trained more than nb_epoch times

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am running deep learning elephas code https://github.com/maxpumperla/elephas on cluster with 3 workers. If i set for example Nb_epoch to 30, it doesn't stop, but it runs again 3 or 4 times 30 epochs. Can anyone help with this issue please ?

How is that possible ? The execution should stop at 30/30.

```
2101/2101 [==============================] - 10s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6103 - acc: 0.7444 - val_loss: 1.1255 - val_acc: 0.5427
Epoch 30/30

 128/2101 [>.............................] - ETA: 8s - loss: 0.4757 - acc: 0.8281
 256/2101 [==>...........................] - ETA: 8s - loss: 0.5443 - acc: 0.7891
 384/2101 [====>.........................] - ETA: 7s - loss: 0.5503 - acc: 0.7812
 512/2101 [======>.......................] - ETA: 7s - loss: 0.5372 - acc: 0.7793
 640/2101 [========>.....................] - ETA: 6s - loss: 0.5590 - acc: 0.7609
 768/2101 [=========>....................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.5685 - acc: 0.7630
 896/2101 [===========>..................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.5730 - acc: 0.7634
1024/2101 [=============>................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.5728 - acc: 0.7705
1152/2101 [===============>..............] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.5794 - acc: 0.7622
1280/2101 [=================>............] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.5891 - acc: 0.7578
1408/2101 [===================>..........] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.5923 - acc: 0.7550
1536/2101 [====================>.........] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.5942 - acc: 0.7513
1664/2101 [======================>.......] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.5953 - acc: 0.7524
1792/2101 [========================>.....] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.5938 - acc: 0.7500
1920/2101 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5868 - acc: 0.7552
2048/2101 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5930 - acc: 0.7524
2101/2101 [==============================] - 10s 5ms/step - loss: 0.5914 - acc: 0.7544 - val_loss: 1.2075 - val_acc: 0.5128
Train on 2101 samples, validate on 234 samples
Epoch 1/30
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're training multiple models.  Once the first one finishes the next one starts training.  You can combine multiple trained models to make an ensemble, which often gives better results.

Answer (score 0):

The worker's train method (https://github.com/danielenricocahall/elephas/blob/master/elephas/worker.py#L26, https://github.com/danielenricocahall/elephas/blob/master/elephas/worker.py#L76) is used as an RDD mapper function: https://github.com/danielenricocahall/elephas/blob/master/elephas/spark_model.py#L162, meaning each worker will call `train` with the supplied training configuration (epochs, batch_size, etc.). So in your case, 3 workers x 30 epochs = 90 epochs total.